# Inputting katakana on Google Japanese Input

Tags: google-japanese-input

How do we use Google Japanese Input 12-key keyboard to input Katakana as the keys are in Hiragana? For example, how do I input アinstead of あ？

Answer (score 3):

Google Japanese Input only has 2 modes: kana/romaji.

There is no hiragana-only/katakana-only compared to other IMEs. However, in kana mode, the suggestion box provides hiragana (normal/small), **katakana (normal/small and full/half)**, kanji, and recently used words as possible conversion.

**Note:** sometimes you need to scroll to the bottom for katakana conversion.

[image: katakana conversion]

<sup>Screenshot resized. Click to view the full-size</sup>